# How to stop console logging for log4j in spring batch?

Tags: maven, log4j, spring-batch

This is my log4j.properties file.

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%L - %m%n

log4j.category.org.springframework.integration=FATAL
log4j.category.org.springframework.batch=FATAL
log4j.category.org.springframework.jdbc=FATAL
log4j.category.org.springframework.transaction=FATAL
```

I have tried changing the logging levels to INFO, ERROR etc. but nothing changes. I have this file in webapp/resources folder and i have added

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:/main/webapp/resources/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to web.xml as well. But making changes to log4j.properties doesn't do anything. I can still see many DEBUG logs in console like this

```
17:06:06.405 [qtp2018468405-39] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
```

How can I control logging level?

Comment: The value of the location in the classpath (`classpath:/main/webapp/resources/log4j.properties`) looks wrong. If your file is inside `src/main/webapp/resources`, it will end up in the WAR in `xxx.war!resources/log4j.properties`). So you can try `classpath:/resources/log4j.properties`, although I'm not sure if _classpath:_ is correct here.

Comment: I have tried this also. Tried with classpath and without it.. But nothing seems to happen.. I also renamed log4j.property, but was no error, the logs are shown in same manner.

Comment: So add this property at startup, you should see exactly what happens (could be your file is not taken, or your appenders are defined badly):       `-Dlog4j.debug`

Answer (score 0):

Logging level can be controled by using `log4j.rootLogger` property in `log4j.properties` file.

In your properties file I see you have not set `log4j.rootLogger` to `INFO`. Hence by default, the root logger is assigned to `Level.DEBUG`.